# javascript constructor with google chrome bugged?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bizarre console.log behaviour in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198912/bizarre-console-log-behaviour-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Given the following script :

```
    var Test = function () {
        console.log("constructor");
        this.positions = [];
        console.log(this.positions);
        console.log("constructorEnd");
        this.addPosition = function () {
            console.log(this.positions);
            var i = this.positions.length;
            this.positions[i] = "aa";
            console.log(this.positions);
        }
    }
    var t = new Test();
    console.log("constructed");
    t.addPosition();
}
```

The expected result is :

```
constructor
[]
constructorEnd
constructed
[]
["aa"]
```

This is what I can see using firebug.
The very same script on chrome (linux, 16.0.912.21 dev) gives me :

```
constructor
["aa"]
constructorEnd
constructed
["aa"]
["aa"]
```

What does that mean ??
Adding a breakpoint in chrome to see what happen make it works (same ouput as firefox) !
Here is a testcase : http://jsfiddle.net/sNzKq/1/

thanks

Comment: It's a problem with the Chrome console, not your code. You cannot reliably "print" the state of an object.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377853/apparently-contradictory-behavior-of-javascript-function).

Comment: That's a bug/problem with the Chrome console as Felix said. But you can write your own log function: http://jsfiddle.net/sNzKq/3/

Comment: Ok Felix and ComFreek are right, this is a chrome console problem. Is there an open issue for chrome about that ?
Thanks

Comment: Found only an unconfirmed bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not clone an object when displaying it in the console, so it will always show the *current* state. To log the state at a certain position, use e.g. jQuery's `$.extend({}, yourObject)` to log a clone.