# Array of objects passed to function is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop, foreach

Ionic app written in typescript:

```
 let files: any[] = [];
 files =this.getFiles("wildlife");
 console.log("files:", files);
  this.render(files);
```

this output says
[image]

which is strange, cause although there are 50 items there but it shows Array(0).
Problem is when i pass this array in function:

```
  render( files) 
    {
     files.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item) <- does not exist

    });
    }
```

Array is empty. Why is that ?
Is there other way to pass the array and loop through its objects ?

EDIT:

```
getFiles(folder) {
    let files: any[] = [];

    this.file.listDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'www/assets/' + folder)
      .then((items) => {
        // console.log(items);

        items.forEach(item => {
          files.push({
            filename: item.name,
            name: this.getName( item.name)
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(err =>
        console.log("error: ", err));

    return files;
  }
```

Comment: you can't use `await` without `async` wrap your code in function mark the function async

Comment: What goes `getFiles` look like?

Comment: I guess you are trying to log them in render function before they are actually there. You are maybe not using async await as you shoud. Could you post more of your code, in order for us to see bigger picture.

Comment: please ignore async/await keyword. Ive tried with and w/out that

Comment: I suspect you are [not properly returning some async response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and you are [looking at this in the browser console which is lazy about evaluating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566290/chrome-and-firefox-javascript-console-different-return-value) so *when you log* `files` it's an empty array but *when you expand it* (different point in time), it's now populated. The code here is not enough to say how exactly to fix it but check my first link.

Comment: I agree with @VLAZ. Please share more of your code

Comment: post updated now

Comment: @Jalle: you're returning `files` before `listDir` has called your callback. So it will be empty immediately after the call and populated at some later time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your `getFiles` function as asynchronous function.

```
let files: any[] = [];
 this.getFiles("wildlife")
   .then(res => {
     files = res;
     console.log("files:", files);
     this.render(files);
 });
```